# Nest if() conditions in php for redirecting different user types to different headers

Tags: php

I am trying to include different headers to different users. How do I layout my if() conditions? I know this is a basic concept.

```
if($_SESSION['usertype'] == "1"){

    // include admin header

    if($_SESSION['usertype'] == "0"])
    {
        // include normal user header
    } else {
        // include non logged  in header ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using switch instead?:

```
switch($_SESSION['usertype']) {
    case 1:
        // ...
        break;

    case 0:
        // ...
        break;

    default:
        // ...
}
```

Looks more pleasing, in my opinion, than the `if/else` approach:

```
if ($_SESSION['usertype'] === 1) {
    // ...
} elseif ($_SESSION['usertype'] === 0) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```